# WFFM Item creation issue

Tags: wffm, multilingual

We have a bilingual site with the languages "fr" and "en". There is a WFFM on a page.

On submitting the form, it will create an item. The owner of the created item will be the name of the logged in user. For "fr" it works fine.

When browsing the page in "en" and submitting the form, the item owner is "sitecore\admin" or some other sitecore\. Why does this happen.

The form is available in both languages and never did any setting/configuration to assign the owner name.

I always want the item's owner to be the logged in user. How can I fix this.

using sc8.0 u5

Comment: Recently faced the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: What is the value in the "Created By" field of the item? Are your WFFM Save Action  (I am assuming the default `Create Item` one) marked as **Client Action=true** or again it is unchecked like default?